# How to check if a set of Lists contain a string value('FAIL') in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a bunch of functions these functions append the string value 'FAIL or PASS in a list and depending on fail or pass a GUI window(PyQT5) should open up.
But even though all the values in all the Lists are 'PASS' the window for 'FAIL' window opens up.
I think my if else condition is wrong if someone could correct it for me or show me how to do it that would be much appreciated.

Please show me a more accurate or the correct way to do this.

```
def checkbox_ledNA(self):
        self.LedResult = []
        self.LED_pass_na = 'PASS'
        self.LED_fail_na = 'FAIL'
        pass_fail_na = lambda state_na: self.LED_pass_na if state_na == 2 else self.LED_fail_na
        self.checkPWR_rot_na = pass_fail_na(self.ui.PWR_rot_NA.checkState())
        self.LedResult.append(self.checkPWR_rot_na)
        self.checkPWR_grun_na = pass_fail_na(self.ui.PWR_grun_NA.checkState())
        self.LedResult.append(self.checkPWR_grun_na)
        self.checkP1_na = pass_fail_na(self.ui.Port1_NA.checkState()) 
def parameter_vergleich(self):
        self.confResult = []

        ####################################################
        if self.ord_nmr == self.artikel_na:
            print("Artikel number matched")
            self.ord = 'PASS'
        else:
            print("Artikel did not  match")
            self.ord = 'FAIL'
        self.confResult.append(self.ord)
        ####################################################
        if self.firmware_version == self.firmwareV_na:
            print("Firmware version matched")
            self.fv = 'PASS'
        else:
            print("Firmware version did not match")
            self.fv = 'FAIL'
        self.confResult.append(self.fv)
def get_output_rx(self):
        while True:
            self.size = self.ser.inWaiting()           
            if self.size > 190:
                self.rx = 'PASS'
                print(self.size, ' RX-Leitung ', self.rx)
                if self.rx == 'PASS':
                    break
            else:
                self.rx = 'FAIL'
                if self.rx == 'FAIL':   
                    break
                print(' RX-Leitung ', self.rx)
                break
            self.rxtxResult.append(self.rx)
            return self.rx

def checkResult_na(self):    
        if 'FAIL' in self.pingTestResult or self.rxtxResult or self.LedResult or self.confResult:
            self.failWindow()
            
        else:
            self.passWindow()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your conditionals. Python evaluates a series of conditionals separated by `or` by evaluating each expression between successive instances of `or` and returning `True` or `False` for each conditional. So, writing

```
if 'FAIL' in list1 or list2 or list3
```

Is the same as saying

```
if 'FAIL' in list1 or if list2 or if list3:
```

which is syntactically wrong but conveys the meaning of what you're asking Python to do.

When presented with something like `if list2`, unless `list2` is empty, the `if` statement will return `True`. So your statement:

```
if 'FAIL' in list1 or list2 or list3
```

evaluates to

```
if False or True or True
```

which evaluates to

```
if True
```

making your 'FAIL' window open even when the actual 'FAIL' condition isn't satisfied.

If you want to check if the string `'FAIL'` is in multiple lists, you need to describe each condition explicitly:

```
'FAIL' in list1 or 'FAIL' in list2 or 'FAIL' in list3
```

And so on.

If you have many strings to search and wanted a more compact way to do this you could place all the lists you want to search into a single list and then use `any`, like so:

```
list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4...]
search_string = 'FAIL'

if any([search_string in each_list for each_list in list_of_lists]):
    do_something()
```

Does this help?

Comment: It Certainly does help, I understand the logic behind it now thank you very much